# Merge statement with views

Tags: sql-server, performance, merge, view

I have a merge statement as below,

```
  MERGE INTO test a
  USING @temptable b ON a.[col1] = b.[col1] 

  WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE 
          SET a.[col2] = b.[col2],
              a.[col3] = b.[col3],
              a.[col4] = b.[col4], 
              a.[col5] = b.[col5]

  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT VALUES(b.[col1], b.[col2], b.[col3], b.[col4], b.[col5]);
```

A table and a table type structure as below (`col1` had been non-clustered indexed)

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[test] AS TABLE
       (
            [col1] [int] NULL,
            [col2] [varchar](100) NULL,
            [col3] [varchar](100) NULL,
            [col4] [varchar](100) NULL,
            [col5] [varchar](100) NULL
       )
```

The problem I want to solve is that when the target table grow big it take more time for merge to complete. In my scenario there will be 90% insert and 10% update for one batch. So, I try to merge by using a view by using a condition like `[col1] > 500000`.

From my testing, the speed increase from 35092ms to 23336ms for upsert the same 50000 records 50 times into a table having total record of 8084328 rows.

Is this the proper way for handling huge table merge?

Comment: Just as a general rule, I suggest avoiding temporary table variables e.g., your `@temptable`. Instead, use full temporary tables `#temptable`. The usual way table variables are used do not have statistics so SQL Server assumes there is only 1 row in it, and designs a query for that.

Comment: Also, to help - are there any primary keys in the table e.g., could Col1 be primary key? If so, you can make Col1 a primary key in both the original and the temporary table - which should increase speed a lot as they will both be pre-sorted on the same field. Alternatively, if you can set the clustering key to be all fields in order (even if no primary key) I think that would help.

Comment: thank for reply, will look into temporary table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Data setup**

I was doing some testing with a crappy data setup, to see what SQL Server did. The main points of difference in different setups was in

- sorting the data
- minimising reads

What I found was that mattered was

- Using a table variable e.g., `@temptable` usually introduced a poor memory grant, because it expected only one row. It then spilled to disk, causing it to be slow. The temporary tables `#temptable` typically worked much better.
- For the original table `test` it worked best when there was only a non-clustered index on `col1`. Essentially, for the purposes of the merge, we only care if the row exists, now what col2 to col5 are.

What I found not-useful for speed

- Adding primary keys (or a clustered index) to `test`, while good practice imo, slows it down somewhat as the inserts need to update the relevant clustered index. If you're inserting into the middle of the clustered index, it takes more time than adding to end.
- For the temporary table `#temptable` holding the data, it often worked relatively well without any specific other indexes etc. In some cases adding a clustered index e.g., `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX #CX_temptable ON #temptable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5);`gave a minor speed improvement, and in other times caused more reads.

**General approach**

Part of the question for this, is what are you worried about? If the whole thing takes a second to run (but locks everything else out for that second), is it bad? If keeping locks as short as possible is the main goal, you could consider alternative approaches.

Other options include

- Doing it in batches e.g., merge 10,000 cases at a time. This minimises the 'locked' period but does it multiple times sequentially. This could also be useful if you're on a server with poor memory availability and if the merge needs more memory than you have. It will, however, use more total processing power in the end, and if anyone is using it in the middle, they may get data that is only partially updated.
- Compare it to doing separate `update` then `insert` commands. Each one of these is likely to be shorter than the merge and use less memory, and the total processing may be a bit longer... but there is a chance it may actually be quicker depending on your resources available. If this is faster overall, you could also wrap these two into a transaction, to block any users seeing partially-updated data.

Comment: Another potential approach is to 'precalculate' data e.g., which rows are to be inserted, and which to be updated. This could reduce lock time. Note, however, than any multi-statement result could run into concurrency issues if you're running the same command multiple times simultaneously.

Comment: The main concern here still the speed, as this is a testing carry out in my testing enviroment. The real scenario is in a server of 64gb ram, 10000 row data merge to 1 billion record table take 3 to 4 min. The table had been partitioned by date. The data structure is similar as the example given just more column and include date data type. The id column has been non-clustered indexed. I also tested update and insert but seem to be slower than merge. Can merge be multithreaded? Thank for the suggestion given and the test you had been done. That help me a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is now outside of my experience in terms of size/partitioning. However, here's a suggestion. For a 10,000 row merge of which 80% is new, basically it should be a 3 step process. 1) For the 10,000 rows, determine which need to be inserted, and which are updates. 2) For the ~2000 that already exist, update them, then 3) for the ~8000 new, insert them. In a normal database, these shouldn't be bad. I'd suggest manually trying the three steps as separate commands to determine where the delays are (e.g., does step 1 take the time because it doesn't use the indexes?)